# I can't unsubscribe firebase firestore react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase firestore in an application with react native. The fact is that I have tried all the unsubscribe forms of the onSnapshot listening events without success and I get an error when signOut.

```
this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('chat').doc(this.props.navigation.state.params.event.id).collection('messages')
async componentWillUnmount () {
         console.log ('componentWillUnmount')
         // this.ref
         // .onSnapshot (function () {}, function (error) {
         // console.log ('error', error)
         //})
         var unsubscribe = this.ref
                 .onSnapshot (function () {
                   // Respond to data
                   // ...
                 });
             // Later ...
             // Stop listening to changes
         unsubscribe ()
     }
```

I have looked through the web, documentation of firebase, stackoverflow, github but what works for others, I do not ...

Comment: Why can't you unsubscribe? What is the problem? If you get an error, please post the exact error message, the stack trace, and the [minimal, complete/standalone code that we can run to reproduce that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have this chat done and improved with realtime database and it works very well but I am not able to find the way to be able to paginate the old messages, that's why I started to do it with firestore, but I realized this problem that when making signout I this error appeared
I have already shared the error and the basic chat code.
Thank you very much

Comment: Please don't post additional information in answers. There's an edit link right under your question that allows you to add the information in the question itself.

Comment: I don't know why but they deleted the example I put in chat and the error stack

Comment: Because you posted them as answers, which is not how Stack Overflow works. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377333/how-to-add-details-to-a-stack-overflow-question